# Нет интернета в эмуляторе в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Я думаю, проблема видна из заголовка. Проверяю путем поиска чего-нибудь в Хроме, где получаю ошибку об отсутствии интернета[image: no connection]

Уже пробовал запускать под dns 8.8.8.8 и выставлять sharing подключения у сетевой карты (не получилось, так как у меня нет вкладки sharing)
[image: sharing]

Что еще можно сделать, чтобы вывести эмулятор в интернет?

Comment: Как организовано основное соединение с Интернетом? Как получаются адреса, используются ли прокси, есть ли фильтры (например по MAC-адресу) снаружи хост системы? Какой IP-адрес получил андроид?

Comment: @ArcherGodson wifi, прокси нет, фильтров вроде нет, где посмотреть ip? Кстати попутный вопрос: есть ли какая-нибудь первоначальная настройка андроид студии (или, скорее, эмулятора), чтобы он получил доступ в интернет, или все должно работать "из коробки"?

Comment: ip можно посмотреть в настройках wifi, первоначальная настройка не требуется, "из коробки" сеть спрятана за внутренним НАТом и не требует настройки, использует хост, как внешний гейт.

Comment: @ArcherGodson "в настройках вайфай" это по 192.168.1.1? Если да, то к ним нет доступа, вайфай корпоративный (если в настройках андроида, то не нашел). Но, собственно, интернет на компьютере работает без проблем, а вот до эмулятора не доходит

Comment: если там всё корпоративное, может просто файрволом коннекты запрещены? что говорить системный администратор?

Comment: @ArcherGodson да, я полагаю, вы правы, так как повилась возможность проверить на другой сети, и интернет работает. Спасибо за помощь)